# how to open my ios Application by scanning QR Code from ios market app?

Tags: ios, xcode, qr-code

My task is want to open my application when the QR code is start scanning on ios device, like android apps, in android apps if qr scanning is detected, after the result it is opening some of the application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before doing this you should Custom URL Scheme register for your app

[Registering a Custom URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

After these steps you need to make  QR code for your app and store in local DB of that app you're using. When scan  QR code then get your app custom url and using this url you can open your app easily. Try this may be help full

after get Your custom url of your app try this for open application..

```
UIApplication *ourApplication = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSString *ourPath = @"your app Custom URL"; //For Example Like this @"com.myCompany.myapp"
NSURL *ourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ourPath];
[ourApplication openURL:ourURL];
```

Comment: Mr Joge. I already followed the tutorial, but my requirement is if the device found the qrscan and the result is geting my app URL Scheme, my app should open. Is this functionality work?

Comment: this code ios opening my app. But The qrcode generation and scanning  is not a mobile part then why should i store it on local db? the user is going to scan qrcode from other app that source is not in my hand.

Comment: You need a specific QR Code of your app. and other app is syncing from live server that server will have your QR Code exit there (That app you are using, on that app server you need to upload your QR Code with custom URL of your app. Using that QR code other app will  sync with server and that will get from server your app Custom URL and using that other app can open your app )

Comment: yes, but some of the market app only supporting. I don't know why.  "Qrafter" app is opening my app. because that app only having "Open app URL" option.

Comment: the url is broken

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be asking to open an app when QR is scanned, and if app isn't installed, open a web page instead of opening some app in phone to scan QR Code.

Apple has developed a feature called [deep linking](https://pureoxygenlabs.com/how-to-create-a-qr-codes-that-deep-link-to-your-mobile-app/), which opens registered apps when a QR Image is scanned by phone camera, if you have Apple iOS 11. Otherwise, it'll open up a web browser to either a website or redirect to app store to download app (based on fallback setting included in QR).

For users with earlier operating systems, "open your QR code scanning app to scan." (as usual). For those who don't have a QR scanning app, they'd need to download one (to scan QR Codes), or upgrade to a device that supports a similar function to Deep Linking.

Either approach seems to have the same goal (to open an app, either by scanning QR with data or opened by user to scan data in QR).